# C# read content of a file accessed via url into byte-array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download, webclient

my company is working with an Excel-file (xlsx) on Sharepoint. For my application I need the **content** of the file as a byte array.

When located on my local machine, I would use `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path)`.

How can I do the same with a file hosted on a server? The url is something like `"https://sharepoint.com/excel.xlsx"`

I tried `new WebClient().DownloadData(url)` but this returns something different I can't use. I think it returns the byte array of the file itself and not the content of the file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than `WebClient`, try `HttpClient`:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://sharepoint.com/excel.xlsx"))
{
    byte[] fileContents = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `response.Content` seems not to be the content of the excelfile. With `ReadAllBytes(localPath)` I get `byte[18491]`, with the httpResponse only `byte[16]`

Comment: Sorry, forget it. My response get always a 401 error. have to look how i can solve that before i can say if your solution was helpful for me

Comment: @Johnathan : would you please give some technical reasons why not use webclient :-)  because i am using webclient, would like to know if any drawback.

Comment: @HabiburRahaman this is as good an explanation as any: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27737601/8126362